# Remove date from time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a form field where the user chooses the time the problem is when i go to look at the table it outputs the time and a date
For example: the user selects 8:26 as the time

This is what shows up on the table
2000-01-01 08:26:00 UTC

all i want is for the time to show up

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :time %><br>
   <%= f.time_select :time,  {ampm: true} %>
```

also not sure if the date showing up is causing the am/pm not to show either

Comment: Is your column is a defined as a :time or a :datetime field? It should definitely be a :time field.

Comment: my column is  t.time :time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the returned value of the time attribute on your object is basically an instance of Ruby Time class, use the following to display the value on .html.erb:

```
<%= instance.time.strftime("%I:%m %p") %>
```

Since I don't know the name of the object that's used on your template, I have named it as instance, you'll need to substitute it with the instance that you are using in your code.

Comment: I got this problem undefined method `strftime' for "{1=>2019, 2=>7, 3=>7, 4=>21, 5=>25}":String
Did you mean?  strip

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps :time field in your table is of type :datetime. Change it to :time